# python : how to check list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to check if each item in `type` is in the dict `typeurl`.
If the URL image is in the dictionary,I will save its name.

Below is my code, but I am not sure whether this is a good way to do this.
Please guide me if there is a better method to write this:

```
type = ['https://test/1.jpeg','https://test/3.jpeg']
typeurl = {
    u'Max'   : 'https://test/1.jpeg',
    u'MIX'  : 'https://test/2.jpeg',
    u'Special': 'https://test/dd/1.jpeg',
    u'Medium'  : 'https://test/3.jpeg',
        }
en = []
for t in type:
    for i in typeurl:
        if t in typeurl[i]:
            print i
            en.append(i)

print " | ".join(en)    #output Max | Medium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with filtering and a generator expression, like this

```
>>> " | ".join(item for item in typeurl if typeurl[item] in types)
Max | Medium
```

Here, we iterate through the keys of `typeurl`, and if the value corresponding to the key is in `types`, then we include that in the result of the generator expression. Finally we join all the elements with `|`.

**Note:** Since we do lookup in types, it would be better to make it as a set, so that the lookups will be faster.

```
types = {'https://test/1.jpeg', 'https://test/3.jpeg'}
```

**Note:** There is a built-in function by the name `type`. So naming a variable with the same name, will shadow the builtin function. That is why I have used the name `types`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more compact.

```
print ' | '.join([key for key, val in typeurl.iteritems() if val in type])
```